# Htaccess rewrite match same patterns

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I make both rewrites work like `http://example.com/something.html` `http://example.com/videos/something/1.html` it always matches the `download.php` one but not the `video.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^videos/(.+)/(.+).html$ video.php?q=$1&page=$2 
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ download.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have these rules as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE] 

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ video.php?q=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ download.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Like for the skip files section.

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@ to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: For which exact URL you're getting this 500 error? I have tested this on my Apache and didn't find any error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^videos/(.+?)/(.+?).html$ video.php?q=$1&page=$2 
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ download.php?id=$1
```

`+` is a greedy operator. This is why `download.php` was always matched.